# Testing Established Workflows in CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I recently created a robust CRM 2011 workflow to handle all of our tasks and I'd like to be able to test it. Unfortunately it includes a 3-week timeout after which it sends an email which kind of stops us from testing it live. Are there any resources available for testing these workflows (without them having real-world implications)?

Comment: We have a timeout sending an email after 3 weeks, I want to be certain that these emails are going to the correct recipients, rendering the templates correctly, and correctly closing the tasks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

standard practice (for want of a better term) is to reduce timeouts to one minute and run the workflow in a development environment before switching back to the correct timeout.

I don't believe that there is any alternative to this method.